# Trying to understand how to include filter and options in a gulp task with main-bower-files

Tags: gulp, bower

I would like to have a gulp task with `main-bower-files` that filters, and uses options, like `debugging` or `includeDev`. I have a `bower_components` directory and I can get the task to work with either the filter or the options, but not both. I know that I can include the options in the `bower.json` file, but I'm curious if and how to do both in the task?

I'm looking at the documentation for [`main-bower-files`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) and I guess I don't understand the documentation where it says: `var files = mainBowerFiles( [[filter, ] options] [, callback] );`

Here's the excerpt from my `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('jsbower', function() {
  return gulp.src(bowerFiles('**/*.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/vendor'));
});
```

I see that I can also use: `bowerFiles({filter: '**/*.js'}))`. I can move everything (css from bower components also goes), no filters, and show the debugging with:

```
gulp.task('jsbower', function() {
  return gulp.src(bowerFiles({debugging:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/vendor'));
});
```

How do I combine the options and filter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up working out to get the JavaScript packages from `bower_components` into a `source/scripts/vendor` directory

```
gulp.task('jsbower', function() {
  return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js', 
    { debugging: true, includeDev: true }), 
    { base: 'bower_components' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source/scripts/vendor'));
});
```

(Thinking... I probably do not need to be using devDependencies, dependencies seems like the right classification for the jQuery and GSAP, where consolelog is more like a devDependcency?)

Learned from the [main-bower-file doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files#you-ve-got-a-flat-folder-file-structure-after-pipe-gulp-dest-my-dest-path) that addding the `base: 'bower_components` includes the folder stucture, but without all the package's stuff. Which gets this in the `source/scripts`:

```
// from source/scripts/
.
└── vendor
    ├── consolelog
    │   └── consolelog.js
    ├── gsap
    │   └── src
    │       └── minified
    │           ├── TimelineMax.min.js
    │           ├── TweenMax.min.js
    │           ├── easing
    │           │   └── EasePack.min.js
    │           └── plugins
    │               └── CSSPlugin.min.js
    └── jquery
        └── dist
            └── jquery.js
```

The key seems like the first string or array is the filter, then the rest will be options, the main-bower-files doc says that. I think this my simplified translation: gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(string or array,{key:value, key:value}))

Leaving out the `base` using 
`return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js', { debugging: true, includeDev: true }))` will get me:

```
.
└── vendor
    ├── CSSPlugin.min.js
    ├── EasePack.min.js
    ├── TimelineMax.min.js
    ├── TweenMax.min.js
    ├── consolelog.js
    └── jquery.js
```